# Simple custom tag parsing in java

Tags: java, parsing, transform

I have a client that wants to insert videos, images, form elements, etc. into his text while also keeping html elements that tinymce generates.

One thing thing that came to mind is to create special tags that lets him do this, and then use a transformation engine that takes the input -> output.

So for a video tag, it could inject the necessary javascript to make the video player (like a youtube-like player), and for an image, it just makes an image tag and for a form element, it creates an input tag.

For the forms, I thought using ${name} would be alright. Name would be unique identifier for the value that the program could use. He's just have to make sure he didn't duplicate them.

I guess for images and video, I could use BB Code-style tags like [IMG] and [VIDEO].

Is there anything that already does stuff like this in the java space, or do I have to code it from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good customizable parser that can transform BBCodes or you're own tags in for example HTML:

http://kefir-bb.sourceforge.net/